# "mean value problem" for 2-ary functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ be continuous functions with $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$, satisfying: for any $0 \leq x \leq 1$, have
$$f(x,x)=0,\ f(0,x)+f(x,1)=1,$$
$$g(x,x)=0,\ g(0,x)+g(x,1)=1.$$

Prove that there are real numbers $a,b \in [0,1]$ such that $f(a,b)=g(a,b)=1/2$.

Interesting problem, but I have no clue on starting it.